# Set Excel style (background) based on color object

Tags: java, excel, swing, apache-poi

I have a Color object of some color (Awt)
I want to set background of excel with above color

Lets say I have some color green,
now my excel background should be green color.

but hssfstyle.setFillForegroundColor(bgColor);  method accept only short value as parameter.

Is there anyway to get short value(index of color for excel style ) from Color object

I am using `HSSFCellStyle` to set excel background.

Comment: Please show in your question the code that you've tried so far, along with any problems: error messages, exception stack traces, or a description of incorrect results.

Comment: I don't have any idea to implement....
Plz tell me a way to achieve it

Comment: Please see the [Apache POI Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills).

Comment: This may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709121/624003

Comment: The above  suggestions did not help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply POI Custom color using 'Hexadecimal Color Codes' provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188840/apply-poi-custom-color-using-hexadecimal-color-codes-provided)